# What are the grounds for refunding of Symmetra's teleporter?

Tags: overwatch

I have noticed for a while now that sometimes my teleporter will close on its own, and refund a portion of the meter to me.

What factors determine the refunding of a teleporter? What determines how much ultimate charge I receive from the refund?

Comment: I don't really know for sure, but I think if you are defending point A, and placed a portal nearby but the attackers took point A, then the teleporter will be refunded.

Comment: You might also want to check this question which adresses the matter in a more general way : http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/269263/how-is-ultimate-meter-refunded?rq=1

Comment: @kerwan I did see this question yesterday, but I believe mine is sufficiently different from that question. I did not find an answer to this specific question in that thread.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf you're right, I did this because it might add some informations that could be relevant to others users stumbling upon your question, that's why I did not marked your question as duplicate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Teleporters are refunded **when either team's active spawn room changes**. This is why you do not get a refund when the first point of Gibraltar is capped (neither team has spawn room changed), but you do for the subsequent checkpoints.

The amount of ultimate charge refunded is equal to [uses left]/6.

Comment: Good answer, but can you confirm that there are no other conditions for a teleporter being refunded? For example losing point A as defense on a control point map (eg Hanamura)- as the defender's spawn does not change, does the teleporter remain in place until used or destroyed?

Comment: I can confirm (after paying more attention to it) that my teleporter was refunded to me after we lost the first point of King's Row. I had teleported three people, so I received 50% charge back.

Comment: King's Row changes the defender's spawn though, as it's a hybrid. I'm interested in whether or not the teleporter gets refunded when you lose a point that does not change your spawn room on Control Point maps

Comment: I tested on Anubis and apparently the defenders do get a refund even though only the attacking spawn changes. So I'll change the answer.

Answer (score 5):

It might require further testing but from my experience there are 2 things to take into account :

- As @Lyrion said when you have placed a teleporter while defending point A, and the point is taken, you get the refund. This is likely to prevent your teammates from being teleported on the wrong location (and you getting yelled at by them ^^).
- The ultimate percent you receive seems to be based on the number of people who have used the teleporter. I had a game where 3 people had used my teleporter and I was refunded with 50% ultimate bar. This seems logical to me as the teleporter has 6 charges.

The only thing I don't know is if the proximity of the teleporter with the taken point is taken into account. It might need to be tested by placing a teleporter near point B, let point A be taken and see if the teleporter is refunded.